Custom Zapier Integration with Projects - Assigning an organization
I am trying to create an API call to add a project on creation of an invoice, but I have multiple organisations. Usually you'd be able to select which one  to target in zapier via the GUI, but I haven't been able to locate a specific headers tag or similar to do this with an API call.
I've been trawling through the API docs and thought I'd found it with the tenant ID, but that didn't appear to work. Is there a specific one?



This is a current bug I have also run into the past week with the Xero integration (specifically the API Request action). On the "Action" tab, there should be a drop-down where you select the organzation you want to run calls against.
In the API Request action this dropdown is hidden so no tenant_id can be fed into the calls and they all fail (as a comparison you can see the dropdown with other actions such as "Create Sales Invoice"). Raise a ticket with Zapier support to bump the priority of this being fixed.
